# JSON serialization error with Riotapi.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I played around with the Riotapi.net package and i tryed to get the server status, but when i try to do so with this code

```
foreach (var item in riotClient.LolStatus.GetShardStatusByRegion(region).Services)
{
    //some code
}
```

I get the following error

> An unhandled exception of type 'RiotApi.Net.RestClient.Helpers.RiotExceptionRaiser.RiotApiException' occurred in RiotApi.Net.RestClient.dll
>
> Additional information: JSON serialization error

How can I resolve this error?